# What are the properties of the StrongLoop Loopback 'Datasource' Object?

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback

I am working on a custom boot script that will autoupdate (sync database to loopback models) for only SOME of my Loopback models (so as to not over-ride schema changes made by other apps / devs on DBs I connect to inadvertently).

Right now I am using the following in my bootscript to get the datasource object for each of my connected datasources:

```
var postgres = app.dataSources.AWSPostgres;
```

The two pieces of data I would love to be able to pull from the above object are:

1. The name of the datasource (String)
2. An array of Models that are being stored in that DataSource (Array)

> The problem is that I can't find any documentation reference to the properties of the individual dataSource objects.

If I can get the name of the dataSource from the object above (in the case of the example the name would be 'AWSPostgres') then I can create an array of the datasources I would like to make available for Autoupdate thereby exempting the datasources where I DO NOT want to overwrite the existing schema.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to list the properties of the individual datasource connector object using the following bit of code:

```
console.log("Show properties... ", Object.keys(datasource.connector));
```

### Properties for a Loopback Datasource Connector

[ '_models',
'name',
'settings',
'dataSource',
'client',
'log',
'logger',
'_mixins',
'observe',
'removeObserver',
'clearObservers',
'notifyObserversOf',
'_notifyBaseObservers',
'notifyObserversAround' ]

For my purposes I was able to pull the name out of... wait for it... the **datasource.connector.name** property.

For those wondering,  **datasource.connector._models** is an array of the models attached to a given datasource.  To get about the names of each model attached to that datasource you would do something like this (I am using Lodash which I recommend):

```
   _.forEach(datasource.connector._models, function(datasourceModel) {
        console.log("Model name is... " + datasourceModel.model.modelName);
   });
```

The above loops through each model in the datasource.connector._models array and logs the modelName to the console, that will give you a list of the models attached to a given datasource which is usable inside of a Loopback boot script.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering what my final boot script looked like (which sets up to autoupdate ALL models on only SOME datasources) here is my full code:

```
var _ = require('lodash');

module.exports = function (app) {
'use strict'

//Define Postgres_Local Datasource and Models
var postgres_local = app.dataSources.LocalPostgres;

//Define Postgres_aws Datasource and Models to AutoUpdate
var postgres_aws = app.dataSources.AWSPostgres;

//Define Mongo Datasource and Models
var mlab_Mongo = app.dataSources.mlab_Mongo;

//Define MySQL Datasource and Models
var mysql = app.dataSources.mysql;

// Only the Datasources listed in this array will have their Models AutoUpdated
var datasources = [postgres_aws, mysql];
console.log('-- Datasources to Autoupdate: ' + datasources.length);

//Loop through all specified datasources and models to autoupdate where necessary
_.forEach(datasources, function(datasource) {
    console.log("Working on... " + datasource.connector.name);

    var currentDataSource = datasource;

    _.forEach(datasource.connector._models, function(datasourceModel) {
        console.log("Cheking if table for model " + datasourceModel.model.modelName + " is created and up-to-date in " + datasource.connector.name + " DB.");
        currentDataSource.isActual(datasourceModel.model.modelName, function (err, actual) {
            if (actual) {
                console.log("Model " + datasourceModel.model.modelName + " is up-to-date. No auto-update necessary.");
            } else {
                console.log('Difference found! Auto-updating model ' + datasourceModel.model.modelName + '...');
                currentDataSource.autoupdate(datasourceModel.model.modelName, function () {
                    console.log("Auto-updated model " + datasourceModel.model.modelName + " in " + datasource.connector.name + " datasource successfully.");
                });
            }
        });
    });
});

} // End Exports
```